# I trying to separate the bullet point description using trim option in the formula Tex?

Tags: regex, oracle, netsuite

I want to use such type of function of NetSuite  TRIM(LEADING' ' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR({storedescription}, '[^:]+', 1, 2)) to separate the bullet points from save search results.Or can you please tell what is the REGEXP_SUBSTR for bullet point(

in the UI).

[This is my store description on inventory item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59sqB.png)

[This is my inventory item save search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLwGn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a literal bullet point in your regex to get data anything other than a bullet point. It works as it should.

**QUERY**:
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('• This is first bullet point, • this is second bullet point','[^•]+',1,1) from dual;`

The query you can run in your Toad or SQL Developer and it will return a result for first value after bullet point. You need to increment the last digit as 2,3, and so on as per your need of the string. If you do

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('• This is first bullet point, • this is second bullet point','[^•]+',1,2) from dual;`

Then it will take the second value after bullet point.

**Example:**
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc7ddbe1d29be88b619afeb895d809ab)